# Developing Apps On Your Personal iPhone - Is It Safe?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have been developing iPhone apps on my iPad for a long time and I'm about to develop for my iPhone, but I just wondered is is safe and by that I mean...

1. Can it possibly hurt my iPhone
2. Could it cause the iPhone to glitch or do funny things?
3. Any possible *Cons*?
4. Any *Pros* that I may have missed?

Is developing on your own personal iPhone/iOS devices recommended?

Thank you for all the answers in advance...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. Yes.
3. See 1 and 2
4. Real world usability tests.

My recommendation, do it anyway. You are a developer, a smart guy, a tinkerer. If things go wrong, just restore back to a backup.

Comment: Oh Yea, I forgot all about back ups! Nice advice!

Comment: +1 Edited for readability by non-native speakers who might experience difficulties with certain words not commonly found in technical literature :)

Comment: Of course, it's still ideal to have a dedicated test device handy, either a similar model as a benchmarking control or a different one for testing on different device capabilities. Just be careful that some backups may fail due to incompatibility issues. (Comment posted from my personal iPhone running a development build of iOS...)

Comment: @coneybeare can you explain what and how on point 1? your answer got me curious...

Comment: @Jasonw Not going through the app store and doing a direct install means s/he could use private apis. It is unlikely, but perhaps s/he makes some destructive deletes. Perhaps s/he writes code to leave the flashlight on for days, or keep the cores running at 100% for days. I think the sandbox is pretty stable, but I have made a private app that purposely crashes springboard before :)